# How do I REALLY get started programming in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out where exactly to go in order to write the Ruby code itself. I know that I can enter things line-by-line in Terminal (I'm on a Mac), but I'd like to figure out how to start using something like Xdrive (Apple won't allow me to download Xrive because I have OS X 10.5, not 10.6).

What steps do I need to take in order to start writing code in a program like xDrive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Xcode and not Xdrive? Xcode version 3.1.x is what you need for 10.5 - create a free account at Apple Developer Connection at http://connect.apple.com (if you haven't already) and in the Developer Tools subsection of Downloads (about halfway down) you will find it.

There's a nice intro at http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html

Answer (score 0):

I started with the book "Agile Web Development with Rails"

I suggest you look at that book in a bookstore. If it isn't of help, then you may need to take a class on software development first. Or look for a more introductory book about programming in general.

Ruby and Ruby on Rails are not simple systems if you haven't written/developed software before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I meant Xcode, not Xdrive. Sorry about that.

I had created an Apple developer account, but when I tried to download Xcode, there was only one download available.

Comment: Hi Nate, you can comment on answers (see the "add comment" button).  So this would be more appropriately done as a comment on Stuart's response than an "answer".  You should probably delete this answer (look for the "delete" button)